# NoMethodError: undefined method `add_a_file' for Testmethod:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

What is causing this error? It doesn't matter whether or not `self.` is specified.

```
class Testmethod < ApplicationController
  def add_a_file(files, next1, f)
    true
  end
  next1 = 0
  files = Array.new
  Dir.chdir("db/testdir")
  Dir["*.xls*"].each do |f|
    self.add_a_file(files, next1, f)  # Error thrown here.
    next1 += 1
  end
  Dir["*.csv*"].each do |f|
    self.add_a_file(files, next1, f)
    next1 += 1
  end
  sfiles = files.sort { |first, second| first[1] <=> second[1] } # ASC by mdate
  puts sfiles.inspect
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to call `add_a_file` method on `Testmethod` class (`Testmethod.add_a_file`) instead of on its instance. Either you should create this class' instance with:

```
instance = self.new
```

or make `add_a_file` a singleton method (class method):

```
def self.add_a_file(files, next1, f)
  true
end
```